# Need Help Mocking API Data in Flutterflow for Testing and Collaboration

Tags: flutter, mocking, flutterflow

I'm currently working on a Flutterflow project where one of my screens makes an API call upon loading. However, the API I'm using is hosted externally, and I'm encountering some challenges with testing and collaboration.

Here's the scenario: Currently, my screen makes a call to an external API upon loading. However, for testing purposes and to streamline collaboration, I'm aiming to mock the API data locally before sharing the build with others.

I've attempted to directly pass mock request responses into the code. However, due to the external API returning a 404 error, this approach isn't feasible.

Could anyone provide suggestions or best practices on effectively mocking API data in FlutterFlow projects? I'm familiar with the JSON response format and wish to ensure that others can test the screens without relying on the external API.

Any insights or tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!